# Why does -1 Match Type Match return N/A?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Suppose I have this formula

```
=MATCH(16,{5;10;15;20;25},-1)
```

Why does it return N/A? I would expect it to return 4.

[image: Greater Than]

But What confuses me more is that when I change it to a Less than Match(1) it works as expected.

[image: Less Then]

And even though I knew it would match the wrong thing I still thought it would be good to include I tried all values as Text and it did not return N/A, although it also return `1` no matter what I replace `16` with

[image: Text Match]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct.

- with -1 The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in
  descending order
- with  1 The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending  order

Comment: Wow, That makes sense. I assumed that didn't matter because the tool tip that pops up specifically says that for `0` it can be any order, but for `-1` and `1` it doesn't mention order at all.